# Publish as a book, then request a journal for peer review or reverse

Tags: publications

I am planning to publish my research as a book containing parts as a biography, then is it possible later to request a journal to peer review the research? or can publish as a peer review in a journal, then publish as a book?

Comment: What is in it for the journal? The work is already published.

Comment: I want to send it to the journal to peer review the paper, it's more for me.

Comment: Right - so why should a journal provide you with a service that they get no return on?

Comment: That is right, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, journals want to publish new research, stuff that hasn't been shared before.

Comment: Thanks, Staniss, can you do the reverse, can publish as a peer review in a journal, then publish as a book

Comment: First the journal, then the book is also unlikely. You normally give up your copyright when you publish in a journal. Sometimes arrangements can be made, but it isn't a common thing.

Comment: Thank you Buffy

Comment: @Buffy: That depends. A lot of journals offer open access options, often for a substantial fee, where the authors retain full copyright, and merely grant the journal a license to distribute the paper. In such cases, subsequent publication as a book is generally possible.

Comment: In some fields it is totally standard to publish your work as journal articles first, and later publish it in expanded form as a book.  Nobody does that in my field, though.